Visual puzzle with a grid
Puzzle I composed, the reasoning matters more than the correct answer.


 Hint: Quark.


My advice is instead of trivializing the puzzle with the hint I think it would have been better to put the Physics tag instead.

With the hint in place
The arrows

 Refer to UP and DOWN QUARKS.

The rectangles with dots

 Represent TOP and BOTTOM QUARKS.

The grids

 show the amount and type of charge each one possesses. Up quarks have a charge value of +2/3e whilst down has a value of -1/3e hence why the orange bar is twice as long in the top grid and the negative sign for the bottom. This is the same for Top and Bottom quarks too.

So for the bottom right

 It only needs to have the same as the bottom left grid.


With the grid being eight squares wide, the orange bars comprise 3/4 and 3/8 respectively. It would work better if the grid was nine squares wide.

And... didn't you have a completely different answer to this already accepted?

Yeah apparently it was wrong the OP unaccepted it I noticed then added a hint. He must have made an error.

the bar length ratio between the quarks is what is important here.
